# RESTful API with Express and MySQL. Can't query anything on GET request

Tags: mysql, express

Hey y'all I have been having a little trouble with Express JS and implementing API's. Basically, when the path is `/movies` I want it to fetch ALL movies from the database. Sound good?

So, I set up my app.js as such: `app.use('/movies', movieRouter);` and I have the database and table created and connected. Now... this is where I am totally confused. `err` and `movies` is undefined, even though I imported mysql, and all necessary modules to connect to the database.

```
movieRouter.route('').get(function(req, res){
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM movies"),function(err, movies) {
        if(err){
            res.status(500);
            res.send("Internal Server ERROR!")
        }
        else {
            res.status(200);
            res.send(movies);
        }
    }
    connection.end();
    // res.send("TEST")
});
```

I would appreciate if anyone can give me a hand, I just don't want to use MongoDB and every tutorial in the Universe only uses Mongo.

Also, would appreciate any kind of criticism, as to whether this is a good approach!

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a bracket  connection.query("SELECT * FROM movies"**)**.
That was all.